Desiring production vs Social production
I'm currently reading AntiOedipus (have read Deleuze's book on Nietsche before) and I'm struggling to understand what's the difference exactly between desiring production and social production, since the terms are used somewhat differently in different contexts.
Please, correct me if I'm wrong.
In simplest terms, let's say there's an inherent desire to live, to do things in a person, a generalized Nietsche's will to power. The person lives in a society which in different ways puts some limits on what a person can do. This is manifested in state laws, traditions, etc., but in a more immediate social interactions it becomes difficult to describe.
Here's a simple example. Let's say there's a group of people who draw. Some guy comes in and draws some weird stuff instead of portraits and landscapes like people around him. In this group, such a person is somewhat alienated and that's basically what limiting is in a sense of having a resistance to doing something you want instead of something that is allowed in a society/local group of people. Not that someone in particular is enforcing anything, but there's some kind of resistance to anything that isn't shared by the people around, status quo.
What happens in this situation? There isn't really any kind of utility in drawing portraits/landscapes exactly. This guy just does what he does and doesn't see drawing portraits/landscapes as some separate category that is different from drawing anything else. And the people in this group probably won't be able to explain why they draw portraits/landscapes as well.
Would Deleuze call what people in this group do social production? Would Deleuze say that there's some kind of motivation to belong / to fit in the group that forces people to draw portraits/landscapes instead of anything else? What is actually produced in this case and in what sense?
Would Deleuze call desiring production is what drives this one guy? Basically the situation, where the person does something without expecting anything from it? Or more like making a slight tradeoff towards it? Afterall, this guy does come to this group for some reason and not just sitting at home, but do not engage in what people do fully?
Whould that make social production/desiring production kind of a spectrum from totall conformity to total random activity?

Maybe useful Desiring-production (French: production désirante): instead of the "passive" Freudian unsconscious imagination (the "theater") the desire is a productive force, a kind of "desiring-machine".

Anti-Oedipus: "the key term of Anti-Oedipus is “desiring-production,” which crisscrosses Marx and Freud, putting desire in the eco-social realm of production and production in the unconscious realm of desire. Rather than attempting to synthesize Marx and Freud in the usual way, [they] will call desiring-production a “universal primary process” underlying the seemingly separate natural, social and psychological realms. Desiring-production is thus not anthropocentric; it is the very heart of the world. "

See Eugene W. Holland, Deleuze and Guattari's Anti-Oedipus: Introduction to Schizoanalysis (Routledge, 1999): "The Anti-Oedipus is not easy to read. The book starts by describing in minute and sensory details the
workings of what it calls “desiring-machines,” as if their existence or very definition could be taken for granted, and ends up feigning incompetence. 1/2

A-O works by making certain connections – between libido and labor-power, most fundamentally – and by rejecting others – the clinical definition of “schizophrenia,” for example, but also the psychoanalytic definition of desire as “lack.” 2/2

"Just as desiring-production is organized on the body-without-organs, socialproduction is organized on what Deleuze and Guattari call the “socius”: the earth for savagery, the despot for barbarism, capital for capitalism. It is not only the socius, as the social focal-point for the investment of productive desire, that varies historically: so does the very nature of the relationship between desiring-production and social-production."
